# How to make the unit joined in the for looped variable

Tags: python, for-loop

```
for i in range(5, 11):
    print("{:>4}".format(i),"'", "  |  ", "{:>5}".format(round(i*0.3048, 2),"m"))
```

the output is

```
5 '  |  1.52 m
```

and continues

I want it to be

```
5'  |  1.52m
```

Comment: Python 3.6+ - try this [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) : `f"{i:>4}' | {round(i*0.3048, 2):>5}m"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the `m` out of the format function, second, set the `sep` parameter of the `print` function to an empty string, which is a space by default:

```
for i in range(5, 11):
    print("{:>4}".format(i),"'", "  |  ", "{:>5}".format(round(i*0.3048, 2)),"m", sep='')

"""
   5'  |   1.52m
   6'  |   1.83m
   7'  |   2.13m
   8'  |   2.44m
   9'  |   2.74m
  10'  |   3.05m
""""
```

Answer (score 0):

print function takes 'SPACE' as default separator, you can change it :-

```
print("First","Second",....,sep="")
```

OR
Instead of :-

```
format(round(i*0.3048, 2),"m")
```

Do this :-

```
format(str(round(i*0.3048, 2))+"m")
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass multiple arguments to `print`; create *one* formatted string to print.

```
>>> for i in range(5, 11):
...     print("{:>4}' | {:>5}m".format(i, round(i*0.3048, 2)))
...
   5' |  1.52m
   6' |  1.83m
   7' |  2.13m
   8' |  2.44m
   9' |  2.74m
  10' |  3.05m
```